# Remove for loops from math expression in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Given the following expression I would like to calculate it without using for loops. The range for i,j is the same (self.dims[0]).

[image: Equation]

My current implementation is:

```
dLoss_W1 = np.zeros(self.dims[1], self.dims[0])

for i in range(self.dims[0]):
    for j in range(self.dims[0]):
        dLoss_W1[i] = (
            d_k(self.param['W1'][i], self.param['W1_t'][j]) -
            d_k(self.param['W1'][i], self.param['W1'][j])
        )
def theta(u,v):
    return np.dot(u,v)/(np.linalg.norm(u)*np.linalg.norm(v))

def d_phi(theta):
    return 1/(2*np.pi)*1/sqrt(1-theta**2)

def d_k(u,v):
    return d_phi(theta(u,v))*(u-(u.T.dot(v).dot(u)))

def nInit(self):    
    np.random.seed(seed)
    self.param['W1'] = np.random.randn(self.dims[1], self.dims[0])     
    self.param['W2'] = np.ones(self.dims[2], self.dims[1])             
    return

def teacher(self):    
    np.random.seed(seed+1)
    self.param['W1_t'] = np.random.randn(self.dims[1], self.dims[0])     
    self.param['W2_t'] = np.ones(self.dims[2], self.dims[1])             
    return
```

Comment: What is the function *d_k* doing? What is the content of *self.param*?

Comment: Whether you can "vectorize" this depends upon `d_k`.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Two of your included functions are never used (some seemed to be class methods), variables are undefined. The names of *d_k*'s arguments and your formula are swapped, just like your *dims* compared to the usual `shape` (why would you do that?). Please include a [MRE].

Comment: I agree the code looks buggy.  But also you need to clearly identify for yourself (if not use) the expected dimensionality at each level.  Where is a variable a scalar, 1d, 2d etc?  To "remove loops" from code that passes 1d arrays to its functions, you need to rewrite those functions to work with 2d arrays.  You many need to replace the `dot` with `matmul`, and specify `axis` when using `norm`.